# Creating a test application for a CSV parse library

Tags: java, csv

For an assignment I had to create a CSV parser library in Java. I have the following code so far: Can you please help me figure out how I would create a test application that can use the library.

```
package demo;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.String;

public class CSV {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner xinput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the File");
        String s = xinput.next();
        x.close();   
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(s));
        scanner.useDelimiter(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");
        System.out.println("Enter delimiter");
        Scanner scanner1v = new Scanner(System.in);
        String formaty = scanner1v.nextLine();
        String format = y ;
        while(scanner.hasNext()){
            System.out.printlnprint(scanner.next()+format);    
        }
        scanner.close();
        input.close();
        v.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Add indents to your code.

Comment: Please format your code (always).

Comment: What you wrote is a method (or function) in a class. This one ("main") is special, as it is the one getting called when you start the class in the commandline. So (unfortunately), what you have written here is not a library at all. If you want to write a library, you should think about the interface. And thanks for formatting the code ;-)